# Match zero or more spaces using sscanf

Tags: c, string, parsing, scanf

Let's have this code

```
char input[] = "key: value";
char key[32], value[32];
sscanf(input, "%31[^:]:%*[ ]%31s", key, value);
```

There can be zero or more spaces after the `:`, I'd like to store the key ond value into c-string variables. The code above can work with one or more spaces, but tough luck with zero spaces.

Is there a simple way how to parse such strings? No necessarily sscanf, but I'd like to avoid regex.

**Edit**

I found a [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) supporting the accepted answer (what an useful, but non-intuitive feature):

> the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters
>   encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace
>   characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace).
>   A single **whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of
>   whitespace characters** extracted from the stream (**including none**).

Comment: possible duplicate of [scanf format specifier to read zero or more characters from a set of characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719469/scanf-format-specifier-to-read-zero-or-more-characters-from-a-set-of-characters)

Comment: @PaulRoub: the situations are related, but I think this is different from the possible duplicate.  In particular, there is a simple solution to this question; I don't think there's an alternative to the 'try it twice if necessary' answer in the other question.

Comment: I would suggest using strstr to find the ':' replace the ':' with '\0' then strncpy() to get the first string.  then using the previously acquired ptr to the '\0', step forward to the next non ' ' char, then perhaps sscanf() to retrieve that second string.  Another method would be to use strtok()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `"%31[^:]:%31s"`.

The `%s` conversion specification skips leading blanks anyway, and stops at the first blank after one or more non-blanks.

If you decide you need blanks in the second field, but not the leading blanks, then use:

```
"%31[^:]: %31[^\001]"
```

(assuming it is unlikely that your string contains control-A characters that you're interested in). The blank in the format string skips zero or more blanks (strictly, zero or more white space characters).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I can't believe that I didn't know this.

Comment: I assumed it was simple oversight or over-thinking after using the negated scan set. :D  Sometimes, it just needs a second person to take a look (though there were comments indicating others were also not sure).  The `scanf()` family of functions are endlessly subtle; they are not easy to master.  At least you're using `sscanf()`; that's easier to handle because if the first attempt fails, you can go back and try again with a second format string (and you've got the string to use in any error message, not just debris).  That's not possible with `scanf()` and the other file-reading variants.

Comment: Or `"%31[^:]: %31[^\0]"`

Comment: @user3386109: I wondered about that (`"%31[^:]: %31[^\0]"`) briefly while I was answering, but using it means you're passing an ill-formed scan set to `sscanf()` as the format string, which is why I used `\001` in lieu of `\000` (aka `\0`).  I don't think that using `\\0` would work either.  `sscanf()` can't read the format string beyond the first null byte, even if the null byte is in the middle of a scan set — one disadvantage of C's null terminated strings compared to a 'pointer plus length' notation.

Comment: Ah, you're right. The `\0` just terminates the string at that point.  So it appeared to work in a quick test, but it didn't work the way I thought it was working.

Comment: "%31c" would be an alternative. However, it is unclear how reading less than 31 characters affects the return value (the spec is vague, glibc increments the return value as soon as at least one character is read, but other implementations indicate the matching failure in the return value, afaik). And there is no 0-terminator added (and it's impossible to tell how many characters have been read), so `value` needs to be zeroed before.